# FreeBSD jail IMAP/MTA config recommendations

Tags: imap, freebsd, smtp, mta

I've got access to my "own" FreeBSD jail. The jail has only basic, unconfigured system, but I have full access to FreeBSD ports, and (jail)root too. Now I need to setup my jail as IMAP/MTA.

The question: What packages are EASIEST for config and later administration, (the simplest possible setup, with the minimum needed configuration) when:

- i haven't any preferences (don't know any yet)
- my (one) domain is managed by ISP, so don't need DNS
- need only IMAP for few users (up to 20 mailboxes)

  - need secure transport layer (IMAPS/993)
  - password auth, no LDAP, no kerberos, nor databases, nothing like fancy things...
- need easy-setup easy-admin MTA, with

  - simplest possible password SMTP auth, (again no LDAP, nor DB),
  - secure transport layer
  - but would be nice have virus-scan
  - and some anti-spam protection

So, what ports I should install for MTA and IMAP?

- MTA (Sendmail, Postfix, Exim)?
- antivirus (ClamAV)
- antispam???
- IMAP(S), (Dovecot, Courier)

when the main criteria are: **easy setup**, and easy administration.

When I googled I found only complicated setups for thousands of users with LDAP, databases and so on - too big-caliber for my small (easy?) needs.

Any pointer to an easy howto is very welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [iRedMail](http://www.iredmail.org/index.html), which is an combination of several open-source programs and a management web interface. It is open source, but there is a payware Pro version of the web interface that offers more features.

If you don't mind DIY, [this tutorial](https://workaround.org/ispmail/squeeze) should help you get started.